# Radio button set needs a selection limit in custom control

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

```
public HtmlGenericControl fieldset = new HtmlGenericControl("fieldset");
public HtmlGenericControl legend = new HtmlGenericControl("legend");

String[] options = ListString.Split(',');
for (int i = 0; i < options.Length; i++)
{
    RadioButton aRadioButton = new RadioButton();
    aRadioButton.Text = options[i];
    fieldset.Controls.Add(aRadioButton);
}

fieldset.Controls.add(legend)
```

Yet when the radio list appears on my page, multiple radio buttons are selectable. How do I restrict the selection limit to 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
aRadioButton.GroupName = "myGroup";
```

Each `RadioButton` must be in a group so that it knows when to deselect the others from the same group.

Comment: This effectively sets the `name` attribute of the HTML `button`, which causes all of the buttons with the same name to be controlled as a group.

Comment: Thanks for completing my answer :)